# What happened during the ending of "The God Engines" by John Scalzi?

Tags: john-scalzi, the-god-engines

What happened at the end of the book?
It seems that the old powerful god has been defeated by the gods that rebelled against it, what is going to happen on all lives on earth, after such an dramatic change?